# Spark streaming to PowerBI in Python

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, powerbi, apache-spark-sql

Is there any github repo where I can integrate my pySpark Spark streaming code with PowerBI? And I want it real time.

This is the last piece in my puzzle.

Comment: You need to stream your data into some data storage, and configure Power BI to read from that data storage.

Comment: But that will not be real time. Is it?

Comment: If you setup "live connection" it will.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and can't contact the end user who has windows. Can you confirm me what data sources are supported in the live connection PowerBI service? Is HDFS supported? I have my own cluster of it and not using HDInsight.